# Show that the following sets are equal:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm stuck on the below question. I understand that to show the equality of sets, I need to show A is a subset of B and vice versa. However, I'm not able to get to the solution.

$$ A = \{ (t^2, 2t) : t \in \mathbb{R}\} \quad  \text{and}\quad  B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y^2=4x\}$$

Comment: Ahh! Give me two minutes, will edit it in. The picture didn't seem to upload!

Comment: @hello1994 Please avoid using a picture, use Mathjax instead

Comment: Thank you both for your quick responses. I have now inserted a poorly formatted equation. Sorry, I'm still learning slowly :'(

Comment: $A \subset B \land B \subset A$

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your equation...you can click on "edit" to see the syntax I used to insert text.

Comment: Let $(x,y) \in B$, then $y^2=4x \implies \left(\frac{y^2}{4}, y\right) \in B$. But $\left(\frac{y^2}{4}, y\right)=\left(\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2, y\right)$, so we can choose $t=\frac{y}{2}$. This shows that $(x,y)=\left(\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2, y\right)=(t^2,2t) \in A$

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to convince yourself that $B = \{ (x^2,y)  \mid y^2 = 4 x^2 \} $

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,y) \in A$, hence there exists $t \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x=t^2$ and $y=2t$ and this entails $y^2 = 4t^2 = 4x$, i.e. $(x,y) \in B$. Thus $A \subseteq B$.

On the other hand, let $(x,y) \in B$ so $y^2 = 4x$ and $x = (y/2)^2$; if you call $t$ the number $y/2$, you get that there exists $t \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x=t^2$ and $y=2t$, therefore $(x,y) =(t^2, 2t) \in A$. Hence $B \subseteq A$.